# Want to remove the time from the DataTable Date column

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, date, datetime, datatable

```
    DataTable dt = TypeConveriontHelper.ConvretExcelToDataTable(SourceAppFilePath);

    string targetPath = BatchFolderPath + @"\" + "TRANSACT.INX";
    StreamWriter wrtr = null;
    wrtr = new StreamWriter(targetPath);
    for (int x = 0; x < dt.Rows.Count; x++)
    {
        string rowString = "";
        for (int y = 0; y < dt.Columns.Count; y++)
        {
            if (y == dt.Columns.Count - 1)
            {
                rowString += "\"" + dt.Rows[x][y].ToString() + "\"";
            }
            else
            {
                rowString += "\"" + dt.Rows[x][y].ToString() + "\"~";
            }
        }           
        rowString = rowString.Replace("\"", String.Empty).Trim();
        wrtr.WriteLine(rowString);

    }
    wrtr.Close();
    wrtr.Dispose();
```

Datatable returns "Date" column which includes Time along with Date. But I need to display only the date. Provide me a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Is the datatype of your column actually a datetime?

Comment: You can print out your date using format. Here a quick reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx

Comment: @LukeHennerley, I am importing values from excel to datatable. One field contains date.

Comment: @John sorry for late reply but posted you an answer which I have tested and is a lot neater

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rowString += "\"" + DateTime.Parse(dt.Rows[x][y]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "\"";
```

or fully implemented like:

```
DataTable dt = TypeConveriontHelper.ConvretExcelToDataTable(SourceAppFilePath);

        string targetPath = BatchFolderPath + @"\" + "TRANSACT.INX";
        StreamWriter wrtr = null;
        wrtr = new StreamWriter(targetPath);
        for (int x = 0; x < dt.Rows.Count; x++)
        {
            string rowString = "";
            for (int y = 0; y < dt.Columns.Count; y++)
            {
                string dateTimeString = dt.Rows[x][y].ToString();
                DateTime dateTime;

                if (DateTime.TryParse(dateTimeString, out dateTime))
                {
                    string formattedDate = dateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

                    if (y == dt.Columns.Count - 1)
                    {
                        rowString += "\"" + formattedDate + "\"";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rowString += "\"" + formattedDate + "\"~";
                    }
                }
            }
            rowString = rowString.Replace("\"", String.Empty).Trim();
            wrtr.WriteLine(rowString);

        }
        wrtr.Close();
        wrtr.Dispose();
```

like michele said see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx for full reference

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime dateAndTime = DateTime.Parse(string);
DateTime dateOnly = dateAndTime.Date;
```

or [DateTime.ToShortDateString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx)

```
String dateString = dateAndTime.ToShortDateString();
```

or [Custom Date and Time Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

```
dateAndTime.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy");
```

For your code:

```
    StringBuilder rowString = new StringBuilder();
    int dateTimeColumn = 3;
    for (int y = 0; y < dt.Columns.Count; y++)
    {
        string cellValue = dt.Rows[x][y].ToString();
        if(y == dateTimeColumn)
        {
            DateTime dateAndTime = DateTime.Parse(cellValue);
            cellValue = dateAndTime.ToShortDateString();
        }
        rowString.Append(cellValue);
        if (y != dt.Columns.Count - 1)
        {
            rowString.Append("~");
        }
    }
    wrtr.WriteLine(rowString.ToString());
```

Comment: How I have to use the datetime? Whether I need to put inside the for loop. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this regardless of types within the `DataTable` and I have also done it with LINQ for you made the code a lot shorter. Couldn't determine if you were putting in a seperator in, if your not then just replace the `@"\"` with string.empty or a space - it's basically just unioning the column values into one string for the output.

Here is what I used:

```
  var dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("SomeDateField");
  dt.Columns.Add("OtherField");
  dt.Columns.Add("AnotherOtherField");
  dt.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now, "Test", "Test");

  var rowStrings = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(x => String.Join(@"\", dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(y =>
  {
    DateTime dateOut = new DateTime();
    if (DateTime.TryParse(x[y.ColumnName].ToString(), out dateOut))
      return dateOut.ToShortDateString();
    else
      return x[y.ColumnName];
  }).ToArray())).ToList();
```

If the column value can parse to a string, then use the "ToShortDate" of the string.

Instead of manually disposing the writer also, I tend to use "Using" and it will call dispose for you even if there is an exception.

```
  using (StreamWriter wrtr = new StreamWriter(""))
  {
    foreach (string rowString in rowStrings)
    {
      wrtr.WriteLine(rowString);
    }
  }
```